# Loading the audio before performing the onclick audio play

Tags: javascript

So I have this script below.

It works brilliantly, but for some reason when you click the first 3-4 times, the sound doesn't come up.

I guess it loads the audio when you click.

How do I load before clicking, so that when you click, it will be already loaded and the sound will play from click 1.

Need help.

Thanks.

```js
    var clicks = 0;
    function hello() {
        clicks += 1;
  var audio = new Audio('https://www.joiji.com/click.wav');
  audio.play();
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    };
```

```css
            .cat{
                background: url(https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.a5d003f6d8eae2434ac07f1b310f3f41?rik=LCY0xhBKNiUZxw&riu=http%3a%2f%2fwww.designboom.com%2fwp-content%2fuploads%2f2015%2f09%2fgoogle_logo_03-818x600.jpg&ehk=PtBQW0bMoGuZptNFF8o5w4Mpc5qeoLstvbWD8cr6V14%3d&risl=&pid=ImgRaw&r=0) no-repeat;
                cursor:pointer;
                border: none; 
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
        width:100%;
        height:530px;
        max-width: 530px;
        background-size:contain;
    
}

            .cat:active{
                background: url(https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.f09202a9ba570e7f4e6e2ad4a81e76b5?rik=41OxYaWQnJlncQ&pid=ImgRaw&r=0) no-repeat;
                cursor:pointer;
                border: none; 
        width:100%;
        height:530px;
        max-width: 530px;
        background-size:contain;}
```

```html
<font size="5">clicked  <font size="7"><a id="clicks">0</a></font> times</font><br>
<button name="cat" class="cat" type="button" onmousedown="hello()"></button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sound does actually run from the first click but it takes some time to load up.
I found that declaring the audio variable before the function, and also calling audio.play() first inside the function eliminates the small delay.
So your JS code would look like this

```
var clicks = 0;
var audio = new Audio('https://www.joiji.com/click.wav');
function hello() {
audio.play();
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
};
```

EDIT:
If you're clicking too fast, the sound won't play on every single click simply because the audio doesn't get the chance to finish playing before starting again.
There are a couple of solutions for this, you can declare a boolean somewhat like isProcessing which disables the ability to click for 1 second, or the solution that seems much more reasonable is using

```
audio.currentTime = 0;
```

right before calling audio.play().
The currentTime property sets or returns the current position (in seconds) of the audio/video playback.
You can read more about it here [W3schools Audio/Video DOM currentTime property](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_currenttime.asp)